# SharePoint site open in Mozila and Chrome but did not allow me to open in internet explorer

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, internet-explorer

Sharepoint site open in firefox and chrome with different users credentials but internet explorer does not allow me to open same site with different credentials

Answer (score 4):

IE will automatically log you in as the current Windows user if the site is in the Intranet zone in IE either by explicit reference in the `Internet options|Security|Local Intranet|Sites|Advanced` list of URL or by "Automatically Detect Intranet Network".

You can change this by either removing the site from the intranet zone or by disabling automatic login in ``Internet options|Security|Local Intranet|Custom level' (Way down at the bottom of the list)

Answer (score 0):

You can hold down Shift and click right-button on IE shortcut and then select Run as different user. It should help.